# Where can I download CCValidator?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I feel like a bit of a dummy here. I downloaded CCValidator for CruiseControl.NET the other day but can't remember from where.

I'm on another machine now without access to the machine where I downloaded CCValidator, and Googling leads me nowhere except the CCValidator wiki and texts about CCValidator.

Can someone provide the link to download CCValidator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify a version...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/files/

Pick a version here and download the appropriate CruiseControl.NET-Validator...